# Height of left and right sides are uneven - CSS

Tags: css, height

With the following code, I'm trying to get the *leftside* and *rightside* to be the same height despite the fact that I have lots of info on the left and a little bit on the right.  I want there to be vacant space under the text on the *rightside*.  Have I coded wrong or am I missing something?  Thanks.

```
#sides {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-bottom; 40px;
  background-color: white;
}

#leftside {
  width: 62%;
  display: inline-table;
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rightside {
  width: 38%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #808080;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
}  

<div id="sides">
  <div id="leftside">
    <h1>TONS O' TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="rightside">
    <h1>TINY AMOUNT OF TEXT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The computed value of `display` for floated block-level elements is `block`. Therefore `display: inline-table;` or `display: flex;` has NO effect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: inline-table;` from `#leftside`